# Sybase default owner in JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I have some queries against a Sybase database that after some changes in our Java (JDBC) code are failing to execute because the database is returning an error message where it demands we provide the owner in front of the table name but that is something I would prefer to provide in a single place in our configuration. We are using ASE 16.

For example, we had a query like "SELECT * FROM table_name" that will not work anymore unless we specify "SELECT * FROM database_name..table_name"

I think there should be a simple answer for this but I am struggling to find one, thank you in advance.

Comment: will need a lot more details ... Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? assuming this issue was not occurring prior to the 'changes in our Java (JDBC) code' it sounds like you're asking for help in debugging the changes in the Java/JDBC code' so ... what were the actual changes made to the code? sample query submitted to Sybase and the full/complete error message?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify we are using ASE 16